# Wierd nameless folder appears in my Desktop

Tags: windows-7, windows, desktop

I noticed this nameless folder appeared in my Desktop.

[image]

When I right click it, it doesn't have "Properties"

[image]

I tried restarting but it's persistent. I haven't tried deleting it yet as it might be something important. Any ideas what could this be?

**Update:**

Nothing happens when click Create Shortcut

This is what appears when I click Delete:

[image]

When I click Yes, the icon disappears but returns after Refresh.

Now, when I try to Cut and Paste it, an error occurs:

[image]

Comment: As-is your question is too broad, as it could be caused by many things.  If you don't know what it is, and it's not working properly (as demonstrated), then it's not important.  Run a CHKDSK and check for disk/file-system corruption, repair any errors it finds, and then attempt to  delete the folder, and then reboot to ensure it doesn't come back.

Comment: Try checking from a command prompt, if the directory is real or virtual.

Comment: Click off the folder on your desktop wallpaper, press F5 and then see if it goes away. If not, then open an elevated command prompt, type in `TASKKILL /F /IM "explorer.exe"` press enter, and then type in `Explorer.exe` and see if it's gone. Let me know how it goes and if that resolves. If that doesn't work, check out this [Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MqMu-y3CDyM) and use [Unlocker](http://filehippo.com/download_unlocker/) perhaps.

Comment: If you create a shortcut, does anything stand out in the properties of the shortcut?

Comment: What does a `dir /a` on the Desktop folder do? What happens if you try to delete the mystery folder?

Comment: @LMFAO_A_JOKE Unlocker can't see the folder.

Comment: @IMB  See this Microsoft Article of a potential command line solution [Microsoft](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-files/unable-to-delete-a-folder-on-my-desktop-with-no/dcbe0524-bdbf-4aff-a28d-9f84cb03e393?auth=1). This whould work for Windows 7 and this is what I'd use if everything else failed. The command prompt sytax to use will be `for /d %d in (%UserProfile%\Desktop\*) do rmdir /s "%d"` and you will press "N" for no on all folders until you see the blank or empty one and press "Y" for it. If it works I'll add answer for you and others to close the question.

Comment: @LMFAO_A_JOKE I tried it, it looped through the folders but it didn't see the blank folder.

Comment: Try running the command prompt `DIR /X /AD %UserProfile%\Desktop` and see if it'll show it there listed with a short name. If so, run the `RD %UserProfile%\Desktop` command with it's shortname name after `\Desktop\<shartname>`.

Comment: @LMFAO_A_JOKE Still nothing, here's a screenshot http://i.imgur.com/vdquoGi.png

Comment: I'm about out of ideas, you said the reboot of the machine also did not resolve and I assume you ensured the machine power cycled fully and all the way through. I'd run an antimalware scan maybe with [Malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.org/). I assume you already tried the `CHKDSK` which Techie suggested and the taskkill explorer thing I suggested above. But it not, try those things and the full scan with Malware bytes and maybe another full reboot of the machine.

Comment: Here's an article about a FILE with a similiar issue and searching the registry for `HideOnDesktopPerUser` and `HideFolderVerbs` to see if you see anything there [TechSupportForum](http://www.techsupportforum.com/forums/f217/solved-cant-delete-file-542079.html). You might also try booting into SAFE MODE and doing everything there that was suggested as well from me and others. If you cannot get resolved with any of that, update your answer with what all you've tried per all the comments, I'll clean mine up afterwards, and consider a +50 bounty perhaps if no one answers in a day or so.